# Get all availables characters in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, foreach, char

How to get all available characters in a computer in vb.net?
Is it something like .

```
For each char as char in My.Computer.char.all

next
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `avialable characters in a computer`? You meant keyboard?

Comment: It is not a meaningful question  The Unicode standard has room for 16 million codepoints.  The current standard has assigned a little over 110,000 of them.  What you can display on the screen critically depends on what fonts you have installed on that machine.  Easy to tell that you are missing font support, you'll see a rectangle.  Focus on *what* you want to display, not what you *can* display.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (note that some characters are non-printable):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For i = 0 To &HFFFF
        Dim c As Char = Convert.ToChar(i)
        Debug.WriteLine(i & ": [" & c & "]") 'shows in immediate or output window
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: 1. Where can I see the result?

Comment: In the immediate window. Change `debug.writeline` to `MsgBox` if you want to see to screen

Comment: Yep that's what i did. Can you send screenshot of all code?

Comment: MyBad ! another problm was blocking it!

Comment: What about non-BMP characters?  Then again, it's unclear what OP was asking.